# Django Rest Frame not able to get the parent id of the self-nested object

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
******* Models *******

class Category(models.Model):
    category_id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent_id = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}, parent: {1}'.format(self.name, self.parent_id)

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category_id = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField('Start Time', null=True, blank=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField('End Time', null=True, blank=True)
    opponent1 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    opponent2 = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status_id = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{0}: {1}'.format(self.name, self.category_id)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('game-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

******* Serializer ********

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category_id = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am writing an API to get the parent_Id from the category_id from all the games that the API returns. But when I return all the game it does not show the value of the parent_Id.

I also tried to add a subcategory to the CategorySerializer but it still does not work

```
class SubCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subcategories = SubCategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'
```

Can someone help me to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace subcategories with  parent_id in CategorySerializer

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?